# marionette simple event delegation

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I am trying to add a simple event to the children under my compositeview but it is not triggering at all..and frankly I am not sure why, it seems so simple, I could do this just fine with normal backbone.view.

In the example below, the alert is not triggered at all, however when I purposefully change the function name the event binds to , to something else that doesnt exist, it complaints that the function doesnt exist, so I think it's something else...help?

```
    App.View.ContentContainer = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({

        className:'content_container',
        itemView:App.View.ContentBrowseItem,
        events:{
            'click .browse_item':'focus_content'
        },
        initialize:function () {
            //this.views = {} //indexed by id
            //this.create_modal_container()
            var coll = this.collection
            coll.calculate_size()
            coll.sort_by('title', -1)
        },
        focus_content:function (e) {
            alert('here???')
            var $modal_container = this.$modal_container
            var content_id = $(e.currentTarget).data('content-id')
            var $selected_view = this.views[content_id]
            var $focused_content = new App.View.FocusedItem({model:$selected_view.model})
            $modal_container.empty().show().append($focused_content.el).reveal().bind('reveal:close', function () {
                $focused_content.close()
            })
            return false
        },
        onShow:function(){
            this.$el.addClass('content_container').isotope({
                selector:'.content_item',
                resizable:true,
                layoutMode:'masonry',

                masonry:{ columnWidth:64 }
            })

        }
```

EDIT: this is the resulting HTML: http://pastebin.com/uW2X8iPp the div.content_container is the resulting el of App.View.ContentContainer

Comment: what kind of element is the `.browse_item` selector finding? can you post a sample of the HTML that this collection (and it's item views) generates?

Comment: I will post the HTML as soon as I get off work.

PS: I have been a big fan of your backbone.js blog posts :)

Comment: I added the HTML btw, im not sure how I can ping you to notify that I have.

Comment: what code do you have in the `ContentBrowseItem` view? Are you using any `triggers` or `events` to catch the `click .browse_item` within that view?

Comment: ... it seems likely that this isn't a Marionette issue, by the way. Marionette doesn't do anything different with the `events` that you declare. you very likely have some other code, somewhere else, causing this problem. either that, or the declaration of events is wrong.

Comment: Yeah I am pretty sure it's not marionette issue, I am using events, should I be using triggers?

Comment: this is the BrowseContent's code: as you can see there is nothing there http://pastebin.com/LDw2jujC

Comment: well... the last thing i can think of is that I need you to create a JSFiddle that recreates the issue. http://jsfiddle.net if you can get the problems to reproduce in that environment, I can dig in and see what needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Is `.browse_item` a selector for the `App.View.ContentBrowseItem` itemView element? In that case, you need to bind the event in the `ItemView` definition, not in the `CollectionView` definition. The reason is that events are bound when a view is rendered. The `CollectionView` itself is rendered before any of its child itemViews.

Also, if you are opening up another modal view on this click event, I would let the app handle that, rather than your `CollectionView`

Try something like this:

```
App.View.ContentBrowseItem = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  ...
  initialize: function() {
    // Maintain context on event handlers
    _.bindAll(this, "selectItem")
  },
  events: {
    "click" : "selectItem"
  }
  selectItem: function() {
    App.vent.trigger("item:select", this.model);
  } 
  ...
});
```

And to actually show the modal detail view:

```
App.vent.on("item:select", function(itemModel) {
  var detailView = new App.View.FocusedItem({ model: itemModel });

  // You may also want to create a region for your modal container.
  // It might simplify some of your `$modal_container.empty().show().append(..).etc().etc()
  App.modalRegion.show(detailView);
});
```

Allowing each of your views to handle their own events is part of what makes Backbone and Marionette so beautiful. You'll just want to avoid one view getting all up in another view's business (eg. a CollectionView trying to handle its ItemView's events, an ItemView creating event bindings to show and close a separate modal view, etc.)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Event delegation on the containing element uses less memory than an event listener on every item view.